# how to validate confirm password field using validateValue

Tags: validation, ios7, ios8, uitextfield

I have a password field and the way i am using validation is something like this:

```
-(BOOL)validatePassword:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError{
    if (*ioValue == nil) {
        if (outError != NULL) {
            NSString *errorString = NSLocalizedString(
                                                      @"Password must not be empty",
                                                      @"validation: Person, Password empty error");
            NSDictionary *userInfoDict = @{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : errorString };
            *outError = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:PERSON_ERROR_DOMAIN
                                                   code:PERSON_INVALID_PASSWORD_CODE
                                               userInfo:userInfoDict];
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The way i am validating confirm password field is:

```
-(BOOL)validateConfirmPassword:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError{
    if ((*ioValue == nil) ||am (![self.password isEqualToString:*ioValue])) {
        if (outError != NULL) {
            NSString *errorString = NSLocalizedString(
                                                      @"Your passwords must match.",
                                                      @"validation: Person, Passwords must match. error");
            NSDictionary *userInfoDict = @{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : errorString };
            *outError = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:PERSON_ERROR_DOMAIN
                                                   code:PERSON_INVALID_CONFIRM_PASSWORD_CODE
                                               userInfo:userInfoDict];
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The issue what i am facing is, whenever i type exact value for both fields like:

*"password":"test"
"confirmPassword":"test"*

its working fine.

Now when i replace one key like: *"confirmPassword":"tes"*, my validation methods fails as it is not setting value for key.

How can i handle this one issue?